# function returning wrong value while executing

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[fetchkey]
@carid nvarchar(50) =null
as
begin
 select t.TBarcode, t.Status, [dbo].[keyloc](t.Status) as 'Key location'
from Transaction_tbl t 
 where t.TBarcode=@carid
end
```

I have one function associated with this stored procedure:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[keyloc](@status numeric(18,2)) RETURNS varchar(50)
as  begin  declare 
@car nvarchar(100), @keylocation  Varchar(50)
 if @status=0
begin
select @car =  t1.TBarcode from Transaction_tbl t1 
  select @keylocation='With Employee'+'('+@car+')'
return @keylocation
end
```

I am passing `carid` as my `Tbarcode`, but while executing out put is coming wrong

```
my output:

    TBarcode             Status      Key location
    -------------------- ----------- ----------------------
    53012364813          0           With Employee(717164016319).
```

I want to get same `Tbarcode` inside the With Employee

```
Expected output

    TBarcode             Status      Key location
    -------------------- ----------- ----------------------
    53012364813          0           With Employee(53012364813).
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: are you missing a where clause in function ?? for this `select @car =  t1.TBarcode from Transaction_tbl t1 `

Comment: i dont think so..i am missing any thing

Comment: can u provide the result of `select t1.TBarcode from Transaction_tbl t1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning

```
select @car =  t1.TBarcode from Transaction_tbl t1
```

this from your function. Since it does not have proper `where` clause `@car is assigned by the first value of TBarcode` .

Hence the function returns the first value of `TBarcode` from `Transaction_tbl` as output

Try this

```
ALTER function [dbo].[keyloc](@status numeric(18,2),@cardID VARCHAR(50)/*Newly added*/)
 RETURNS varchar(50)
ASbegin  declare 
  @car nvarchar(100), @keylocation  Varchar(50)
   if @status=0
  begin
    select @car =  t1.TBarcode 
    from Transaction_tbl t1 
    WHERE t1.TBarcode =@cardID 
    select @keylocation='With Employee'+'('+@car+')'

return @keylocation
end
```

Procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[fetchkey]
@carid nvarchar(50) =null
as
begin
 select t.TBarcode, t.Status,
 [dbo].[keyloc](t.Status,@carid/*newly added*/) as 'Key location'
from Transaction_tbl t 
 where t.TBarcode=@carid
end
```

Comment: I given where clause like this:select car = t1.TBarcode from Transaction_tbl t1 where t1.Status = @status. but still am getting wrong answer only

Comment: You are giving `where t.TBarcode=@carid` this in your query then how can you give status in function. That also must be same as `where t.TBarcode=@carid`